# Populate column which a range of possible values in other columns: in R

Tags: r

For an example dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(region = structure(1:8, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), class = "factor"), y.2012 = c(5.5, 
NA, 4.7, 3.6, NA, NA, 4.6, NA), y.2013 = c(5.7, NA, NA, 3.8, 
NA, 6.2, NA, NA), y.2014 = c(NA, 6.3, NA, 4.1, 5.1, NA, NA, NA
)), .Names = c("region", "y.2012", "y.2013", "y.2014"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I want to add an extra column (called 'variable') that is populated by the most recent year of data that is available.  For example, 2014 is preferable, followed by 2013, and then 2012.  If no data is available, then NA can be left.

I want to the resulting dataframe to look like:

```
  region y.2012 y.2013 y.2014 variable
1      a    5.5    5.7     NA      5.7
2      b     NA     NA    6.3      6.3
3      c    4.7     NA     NA      4.7
4      d    3.6    3.8    4.1      4.1
5      e     NA     NA    5.1      5.1
6      f     NA    6.2     NA      6.2
7      g    4.6     NA     NA      4.6
8      h     NA     NA     NA       NA
```

What is the best way to tackle my problem?  Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are the values always increase per year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to loop over the rows and get the last non-NA value (as the columns are ordered from smallest to largest years)

```
df$variable <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
                       i1 <- tail(x[!is.na(x)],1)
                     if(length(i1)>0) i1 else NA})
df$variable
#[1] 5.7 6.3 4.7 4.1 5.1 6.2 4.6  NA
```

---

Or another option is with `max.col` and `rowSums`

```
df[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df),max.col(!is.na(df[-1]), "last")*
             (NA^!rowSums(!is.na(df[-1]))))]
#[1] 5.7 6.3 4.7 4.1 5.1 6.2 4.6  NA
```

Comment: It seems like you could just do `apply(df[-1], 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)` by the looks of it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I tguess the OP wanted the most recent year non-NA data.

Comment: I know, I'm just judging by the provided data. Will see what they will reply (if they reply).

Comment: Thanks @akrun - that's great.  I do want the most recent year of data so this code fits the bill.  If I wanted the year which the variable is taken from (as a date column next to variable), how would I add this to your code?

Comment: @KT_1 you can use `names(df)[-1][max.col(!is.na(df[-1]), "last")* (NA^!rowSums(!is.na(df[-1])))]` and add that as a new column

Comment: @akrun - thank you, however that seems to just add 'variable' to every non-NA row and not the year at which the data populated in 'variable' is from - am I missing something?

Comment: @KT_1 Actually, I was getting the column names

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `dplyr` library which has the `coalesce` function (in the development version!). Here we can specify the particular order of columns you want (which may be the case if you have lots of variables in this table, or you have a particular order.

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% mutate(variable = coalesce(y.2014, y.2013, y.2012)) # specify order of columns here
  region y.2012 y.2013 y.2014 variable
1      a    5.5    5.7     NA      5.7
2      b     NA     NA    6.3      6.3
3      c    4.7     NA     NA      4.7
4      d    3.6    3.8    4.1      4.1
5      e     NA     NA    5.1      5.1
6      f     NA    6.2     NA      6.2
7      g    4.6     NA     NA      4.6
8      h     NA     NA     NA       NA
```

Comment: I think this is part of the development version, no?

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like, each year the values increase. Hence, an efficient/straightforward solution could be to use `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, c(na.rm = TRUE, df[-1]))
# [1] 5.7 6.3 4.7 4.1 5.1 6.2 4.6  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your data is just for three years, you could just use the more intuitive:

```
selectYear <- function(y12,y13,y14) {
    selectedYear <- ifelse(is.na(y14),
                           ifelse(is.na(y13),
                                  y12,
                                  y13),
                           y14)
    return(selectedYear)
}

df$answer <- selectYear(df$y.2012,df$y.2013,df$y.2014)
```

With more years, though, this method would get a lot more complicated, and akrun's answer would work better.