# Add column detailing which year data is from

Tags: r

For a sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(region = structure(1:8, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), class = "factor"), y.2012 = c(5.5, 
NA, 4.7, 3.6, NA, NA, 4.6, NA), y.2013 = c(5.7, NA, NA, 3.8, 
NA, 6.2, NA, NA), y.2014 = c(NA, 6.3, NA, 4.1, 5.1, NA, NA, NA
)), .Names = c("region", "y.2012", "y.2013", "y.2014"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I want to add an extra column which records the value of the most recent column.  I have this so far ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112372/populate-column-which-a-range-of-possible-values-in-other-columns-in-r)):

```
df$variable <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
  i1 <- tail(x[!is.na(x)],1)
  if(length(i1)>0) i1 else NA})
df$variable
```

In addition, I want to add (as another column), the year the 'variable' data is from.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Well, to add to your function, if you add `names(if(length(i1...)))`, you will get a list with the colnames each value came from.

Comment: You should definitvely try to reshape your data, from wide to long, having first a record per region x year valid observation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve that with:

```
df1$variable <- apply(df1[,-1], 1, function(x) names(x)[!is.na(x)][sum(!is.na(x))])
```

which gives:

```
> df1
  region y.2012 y.2013 y.2014 variable
1      a    5.5    5.7     NA   y.2013
2      b     NA     NA    6.3   y.2014
3      c    4.7     NA     NA   y.2012
4      d    3.6    3.8    4.1   y.2014
5      e     NA     NA    5.1   y.2014
6      f     NA    6.2     NA   y.2013
7      g    4.6     NA     NA   y.2012
8      h     NA     NA     NA
```

You can replace the empty cells with:

```
df1[df1$variable=='character(0)','variable'] <- NA
```

which gives:

```
> df1
  region y.2012 y.2013 y.2014 variable
1      a    5.5    5.7     NA   y.2013
2      b     NA     NA    6.3   y.2014
3      c    4.7     NA     NA   y.2012
4      d    3.6    3.8    4.1   y.2014
5      e     NA     NA    5.1   y.2014
6      f     NA    6.2     NA   y.2013
7      g    4.6     NA     NA   y.2012
8      h     NA     NA     NA       NA
```

---

As said in the comments, it is probably better to reshape your into long format first and then see which year has the last value. Using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- melt(setDT(df1), id.vars='region', variable.name = 'year')
df2[, year := as.integer(gsub('^y.','',year))
    ][, var := tail(year[!is.na(value)],1), by = region]
```

which gives:

```
> df2
    region year value  var
 1:      a 2012   5.5 2013
 2:      b 2012    NA 2014
 3:      c 2012   4.7 2012
 4:      d 2012   3.6 2014
 5:      e 2012    NA 2014
 6:      f 2012    NA 2013
 7:      g 2012   4.6 2012
 8:      h 2012    NA   NA
 9:      a 2013   5.7 2013
10:      b 2013    NA 2014
11:      c 2013    NA 2012
12:      d 2013   3.8 2014
13:      e 2013    NA 2014
14:      f 2013   6.2 2013
15:      g 2013    NA 2012
16:      h 2013    NA   NA
17:      a 2014    NA 2013
18:      b 2014   6.3 2014
19:      c 2014    NA 2012
20:      d 2014   4.1 2014
21:      e 2014   5.1 2014
22:      f 2014    NA 2013
23:      g 2014    NA 2012
24:      h 2014    NA   NA
```

A similar solution with `dplyr` & `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
  gather(year, value, -1) %>%
  mutate(year = as.integer(gsub('^y.','',year))) %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  mutate(var = as.integer(ifelse(all(is.na(value)==TRUE), NA, tail(year[!is.na(value)],1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the reshape2 package's melt function to convert to long format, and then the stringr package function str_replace to get to a year without the "y." prefix. See below, first the convert to long format:

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- reshape2::melt(df, 
                      id.vars="region",
                      variable.name="yearStr")
df2
```

Output:

```
   region yearStr value
1       a  y.2012   5.5
2       b  y.2012    NA
3       c  y.2012   4.7
4       d  y.2012   3.6
...
```

Then, fix up the year:

```
df2$year <- as.numeric(stringr::str_replace(df2$yearStr, "y.", ""))

df2
```

Output:

```
region  yearStr   value year
1       a  y.2012   5.5 2012
2       b  y.2012    NA 2012
3       c  y.2012   4.7 2012
4       d  y.2012   3.6 2012
...
```

To get to the most recent year rows with year label (using dplyr):

```
library(dplyr)
regions <- group_by(df2, region)
df3 <- filter(regions[!is.na(regions$value),], min_rank(desc(year)) <= 1)
as.data.frame(df3)
```

Output:

```
  region yearStr value year
1      c  y.2012   4.7 2012
2      g  y.2012   4.6 2012
3      a  y.2013   5.7 2013
4      f  y.2013   6.2 2013
5      b  y.2014   6.3 2014
6      d  y.2014   4.1 2014
7      e  y.2014   5.1 2014
```

Certainly less concise than @Procrastinatus Maximus, but the intermediate results might have some benefits for plotting or other analysis.

**REVISED**: Added dplyr to show only most recent data rows for each region.